# Your item was found to have requested/fetched one or more external scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Google Store suspended one of our extension with this following reason:

```
Your item was found to have requested/fetched one or more external scripts. An example of one such instance in your item was found in banks/kkbk.js.
```

But this extension has been there since 3 years and never ever we have called any external script or executed any JS code from remote.

I'm confused if there is some misunderstanding from me. There is no where where there is external code is being fetched fetched.

Nor could I find anything in this file below:

#### I will print the source of kkbk.js

```
/* 
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
"use strict";


var gg_kkbk_LOGIN_PAGE = 1;
ff_add_bank_mapping(ff_get_bkname(gg_pc_NB_Karnataka_Bank), gg_kkbk_LOGIN_PAGE, "Login Page");




var gg_kkbk_SEL_ACCOUNT_PAGE = 2;
ff_add_bank_mapping(ff_get_bkname(gg_pc_NB_Karnataka_Bank), gg_kkbk_SEL_ACCOUNT_PAGE, "Select Account");




var gg_kkbk_OTP_PAGE = 1048576;
ff_add_bank_mapping(ff_get_bkname(gg_pc_NB_Karnataka_Bank), gg_kkbk_OTP_PAGE, "OTP");




var gg_kkbk_TRANSACTION_PASSWD = 8;
ff_add_bank_mapping(ff_get_bkname(gg_pc_NB_Karnataka_Bank), gg_kkbk_TRANSACTION_PASSWD, "Transaction password");




var gg_kkbk_final_pay_sel = "input[name='Action\\.bills\\.ShoppingMall\\.TxnLogin\\.Ok']";




function ff_kkbk_main()
{
    console.log("last url visited was:" + document.referrer);
    console.log("Current url = " + window.location.href);


    ff_kkbk_main_processing();
}




function ff_kkbk_main_processing()
{
    console.log("Entered ff_kkbk_main_processing");


    if (gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.ignorebank)
    {
        console.log('kkbk Bank is set to skipped');
        return;
    }
    var detected_page = gg_detected_banks_page =  ff_kkbk_detect_page();
    console.log("detected-age=", detected_page);






    if (detected_page & gg_kkbk_LOGIN_PAGE)
    {
        ff_ringbell_once();
        //fill the login and pass
        $("[name='CorporateSignonCorpId']").val(gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.login);
        $("[name='CorporateSignonPassword']").val(gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.password);


        if (gg_user_selections.mm_bank_stop_first_step_payment)
        {
            ff_bottomMsg("Stopped in first step of payment");
        }
        else {
            if ($("[name='CorporateSignonCorpId']").val().trim().length > 3 &&
                    $("[name='CorporateSignonPassword']").val().trim().length > 3)
            {
                ff_check_already_reached_here('kkbk-login-pagee', 8, function () {
                    document.getElementById('button1').click();                    
                });
            }
        }


    }
    else if (gg_kkbk_SEL_ACCOUNT_PAGE & detected_page)
    {
        $("select[name='UserAccountsIndex'] > option").each(function () {


            if (gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.account_number && gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.account_number.trim().length > 0)
            {
                console.log($(this).text());
                console.log($(this).val());
                console.log('hello3');
                if ($(this).text().indexOf(gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.account_number) != -1)
                {
                    console.log('hello4');
                    $(this).prop('selected', true).trigger('change').parent().focus();
                    $("select[name='fromAcc']").trigger('change');
                    //$("select[name='fromAcc']").parent().focus();


                    return false;
                }


            }
        });




        ff_check_already_reached_here('kkbk-login-acc-sel', 8, function () {
            $("input[name='Action\\.Bills\\.ShoppingMall\\.MakePayment\\.Pay']").trigger('click');
        });
    }
    else if (0 & gg_kkbk_SEL_ACCOUNT_PAGE & detected_page)
    {


        $("input[name='password']").val(gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.transaction_password);


        $("select[name='fromAcc'] > option").each(function () {


            if (gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.account_number && gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.account_number.trim().length > 0)
            {
                console.log($(this).text());
                console.log($(this).val());
                console.log('hello3');
                if ($(this).text().indexOf(gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.account_number) != -1)
                {
                    console.log('hello4');
                    $(this).prop('selected', true).trigger('change').parent().focus();
                    $("select[name='fromAcc']").trigger('change');
                    //$("select[name='fromAcc']").parent().focus();


                    return false;
                }


            }
        });






        var storage_name = 'kkbknetbankingloginotaccsel';
        ff_get_from_storage(function (obj) {
            var clickbtn = true;


            if ("data" in obj) //previous time already stored?
            {
                console.log(obj);
                console.log("time =" + new Date().getTime());


                if (obj.data + 5000 > new Date().getTime())  //don't click within 5 seconds
                {
                    clickbtn = false;
                }
            }


            if (clickbtn) {
                ff_set_in_storage({
                    data: new Date().getTime()
                }, storage_name);


                console.log("pressing eeee button");


                if ($("input[name='password']").val().trim().length > 3)
                {


                    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
                    $("select[name='fromAcc']").get(0).dispatchEvent(evt);


                    $("a.clsinfo:eq(0)").get(0).click();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ff_show_red_bank(true);
                console.log("Not clicking as clicked just now");
            }


        }, storage_name);




    }
    else if (gg_kkbk_OTP_PAGE & detected_page)
    {
        ff_attach_placeholder("input[name='passcodeEntByUser']");
        $("input[name='passcodeEntByUser']").css({
            'font-size': '4em',
            'color': 'red',
            'height': '3em'


        }).attr('type', 'text').focus().keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($("input[name='passcodeEntByUser']").val().length >= 4)
                {
                    console.log("pressing eeee button");
                    $("[name='Action\\.KTK\\.OtpAuthentication\\.Confirm']").trigger('click');
                    ff_show_red_bank(false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        $("[name='Action\\.KTK\\.OtpAuthentication\\.Confirm']").css({fontSize: '4em', color: 'green', backgroundColor: 'white'});


    }
    else if (gg_kkbk_TRANSACTION_PASSWD & detected_page)
    {
        var trans_sel = "[name='ValCorpTxnPwdTxnPwd']";

        $(trans_sel).val(gg_user_selections.mm_kkbk_details.transaction_password);

        if($(trans_sel).val().trim().length>3)
        {
            ff_check_already_reached_here('kkbk-login-trans-passwd', 8, function () {
            $("[name='Action\\.bills\\.ShoppingMall\\.TxnLogin\\.Ok']").trigger('click');
        });
        }


    }
    console.log('end of game');
}
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}


function ff_kkbk_detect_page()
{
    console.log('in kkbk detect page');
    var ret = 0;
    if ($("[name='CorporateSignonCorpId']").length && $("[name='CorporateSignonPassword']").length )
    {
        ret = ret | gg_kkbk_LOGIN_PAGE;
        console.log('login page;');
    } else
    if ( $("[name='UserAccountsIndex']").length && $("input[name='Action\\.Bills\\.ShoppingMall\\.MakePayment\\.Pay']").length)
    {
        ret = ret | gg_kkbk_SEL_ACCOUNT_PAGE;
        console.log('login page;');
    }
    else if ($("select[name='fromAcc']").length && $("form[name='IRCTCPaymentInput'] table ").text().length  &&
            $("input[name='password']").length)
    {
        ret = ret | gg_kkbk_SEL_ACCOUNT_PAGE;
    }
    else if ($("input[name='passcodeEntByUser']").length && ("[name='Action\\.KTK\\.OtpAuthentication\\.Confirm']").length)
    {
        ret = ret | gg_kkbk_OTP_PAGE
    }
    else if ($("[name='ValCorpTxnPwdTxnPwd']").length && $("[name='Action\\.bills\\.ShoppingMall\\.TxnLogin\\.Ok']").length)
    {
        return ret | gg_kkbk_TRANSACTION_PASSWD;
    }




    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Their rejections are mostly random and usually don't make any sense. However, try to rework the code anyway. Currently you inject lots of js files in all https sites, which is plain bad for performance no matter how you look at it. It's better to load the scripts on demand.

Comment: @wOxxOm your are right. After I've contested now they have changed the reason to : `An extension should have a single purpose that is clear to users`